# Failure retrieving date from MySQL on web server onto iPhone

Tags: iphone, mysql, datetime, date, ios4

I am making an iPhone app which has its database on the web server. The database is in MySQL. I retrieve the data from server onto the iPhone using JSON parsing.

I have trouble retrieving the TimeStamp datatype that I store in my database. When I try to retrieve the timestamp on iPhone, it shows datetime as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

It is basically like this

```
/Date(1297432377000-0700)\\/
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON dates on IPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON dates on IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone)

Comment: Since the accepted link-only answer points to another question, this question is a duplicate of the other one. I will try again to close it cc @Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone).