# Formatting a DateTime object from .NET into a NSDate for objective-c

Tags: objective-c, datetime, date, format, nsdate

I am working with an API that returns a .NET DateTime object into my iOS application. I'm a little confused at what's going on, the DateTime looks fine when it leaves the API, but when it comes in it goes through JSON and comes in as a string that looks like this:

```
/Date(1303884000000-0600)/
```

WTF is that and how can I turn it into a NSDate object??

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Parsing JSON dates on IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone) I found the following function to be perfect:

```
    - (NSDate*) getDateFromJSON:(NSString *)dateString
{
// Expect date in this format "/Date(1268123281843)/"
int startPos = [dateString rangeOfString:@"("].location+1;
int endPos = [dateString rangeOfString:@")"].location;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(startPos,endPos-startPos);
unsigned long long milliseconds = [[dateString substringWithRange:range] longLongValue];
NSLog(@"%llu",milliseconds);
NSTimeInterval interval = milliseconds/1000;
return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
}
```

Comment: Note that this does not handle a timezone offset.

Answer (score 4):

The RestKit library has an NSDateFormatter subclass for just this. Take a look here for inspiration:

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Code/Support/RKDotNetDateFormatter.h
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Code/Support/RKDotNetDateFormatter.m

Comment: this should be the answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what you're getting there is milliseconds from January 1st 1970 UTC, with the -0600 being the timezone offset.  Take a look at this blog post http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/18/dates-and-json.aspx

You would  probably have to write a custom NSDateFormatter to handle a date in that format, or you could format it in .NET (easier), output a string in JSON, and then use a standard NSDateFormatter.

Comment: I can't figure out why there are 3 extra zeros at the end of the string though.
Using unix time converter with "1303884000000" I get the wrong date. If I get rid of the 3 zeros and convert with "1303884000" I get the right date.

What are those extra zeros for (or from)??

Comment: Oh, I guess it's milliseconds since 1970 instead of just seconds. So to parse this as a NSDate, I'd have to strip out all the characters and then compare time since 1970??

Comment: You can do it that way. You could then add/subtract hours to adjust timezone if necessary. Like i said previously, you may want to do some more formatting on the .NET side as it's probably easier that way :)

Comment: Ahh problem solved and a function to parse!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone