# How to parse nsmutabledictionary time in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have parsed the Json using following code

```
- (void) getWorkingCalendar:(NSData *)dataForParse{

    NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString* myString;
    myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataForParse encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"data is %@", myString);

    NSArray * parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataForParse options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSLog(@"parser data %@", parsedData);


    for (NSDictionary *dict in parsedData) {


        NSLog(@"Value is %@", dict);

    }

    [delegate array:locations];


}
```

Output as below

```
2014-04-30 12:44:41.828 Testing[827:60b] parser data (
    "/Date(1399016682788+0400)/",
    "/Date(1399621482788+0400)/",
    "/Date(1400226282788+0400)/",
    "/Date(1400831082788+0400)/",
    "/Date(1401435882788+0400)/"
)
2014-04-30 12:44:41.829 Testing[827:60b] Value is /Date(1399016682788+0400)/
2014-04-30 12:44:41.829 Testing[827:60b] Value is /Date(1399621482788+0400)/
2014-04-30 12:44:41.829 Testing[827:60b] Value is /Date(1400226282788+0400)/
2014-04-30 12:44:41.830 Testing[827:60b] Value is /Date(1400831082788+0400)/
2014-04-30 12:44:41.830 Testing[827:60b] Value is /Date(1401435882788+0400)/
2014-04-30 12:44:41.830 Testing[827:60b] finishDownloading
```

How can I get time slot in NSString from NSDictionary?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: wow... what kind of date is "`14014353123412341234431+0800`"?

Comment: http://currentmillis.com/

open this link, you will know @MichaelDautermann

Comment: your service is returning wrong format of date.. Service side is sending directly date object without converting that into date string..

Comment: these are mili seconds, but i dont' know how to code them in IOS?

Comment: I think I need to convert this miliseconds value into date, but I dont' know how to do so :(

Comment: (long long)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0)????

I saw on that website, but query is , how to fetch value from such NSDictionary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a DateTime object from .NET into a NSDate for objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810033/formatting-a-datetime-object-from-net-into-a-nsdate-for-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to tweak this a bit, but this is what I've used with these kind of dates:

**Header File**

```
@interface NSDate (JSON)

+ (NSDate *)dateFromJSON:(NSString *)dateString;

@end
```

**Implementation**

```
#import "NSDate+JSON.h"

@implementation NSDate (JSON)

+ (NSDate *)dateFromJSON:(NSString *)dateString {

    if (dateString == nil || [dateString isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *header = @"/Date(";
    NSRange headerRange = [dateString rangeOfString:header];
    if (headerRange.location != 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *footer = @")/";
    NSRange footerRange = [dateString rangeOfString:footer options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    if (footerRange.location == NSNotFound || footerRange.location + footerRange.length != dateString.length) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *timestampString = [dateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(headerRange.length, footerRange.location - headerRange.length)];

    NSTimeInterval interval = [timestampString doubleValue] * 0.001;
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
}

@end
```

This example does not include the time zone that is in your date, so you might want to add that.

Then use it like:

```
for (NSString *dateValue in parsedData) {
     NSDate *date = [NSDate dateFromJSON:dateValue];
}
```