# Convert .NET JSON date to NSDate (Swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, date, json.net

Hi I know that same question had been asked by several time and I have already gone through several links [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810033/formatting-a-datetime-object-from-net-into-a-nsdate-for-objective-c), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone), [Link 3](http://zdravevski.com/blog/2012/05/27/json-serialized-date-passed-between-ios-and-wcf-and-vice-versa/) and [Link 4](http://simianzombie.com/?p=2352) and many more.

But still I have not getting success all the solutions are in ObjC I need to perform in Swift. Suppose my input is **/Date(1434668400000+0100)/** for that expected output **19/06/2015**.

I have tried below code and convert it from ObjC to Swift.

**Objective-C**

```
+ (NSDate *)mfDateFromDotNetJSONString:(NSString *)string {
    static NSRegularExpression *dateRegEx = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dateRegEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"^\\/date\\((-?\\d++)(?:([+-])(\\d{2})(\\d{2}))?\\)\\/$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    });
    NSTextCheckingResult *regexResult = [dateRegEx firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    if (regexResult) {
        // milliseconds
        NSTimeInterval seconds = [[string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:1]] doubleValue] / 1000.0;
        // timezone offset
        if ([regexResult rangeAtIndex:2].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSString *sign = [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:2]];
            // hours
            seconds += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sign, [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:3]]] doubleValue] * 60.0 * 60.0;
            // minutes
            seconds += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sign, [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:4]]] doubleValue] * 60.0;
        }

        return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**Swift**

```
func dateFromJSON(string: NSString) -> NSDate {
        var dateRegEx: NSRegularExpression!
        var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0

        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            dateRegEx = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\/date\\((-?\\d++)(?:([+-])(\\d{2})(\\d{2}))?\\)\\/$", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)!
        }
        var regexResult: NSTextCheckingResult = dateRegEx.firstMatchInString(string as String, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.length))!

        var seconds: NSTimeInterval = (string.substringWithRange(regexResult.rangeAtIndex(1)) as NSString).doubleValue / 1000.0
        if regexResult.rangeAtIndex(2).location != NSNotFound {
            var sign: NSString = string.substringWithRange(regexResult.rangeAtIndex(2))
            seconds += NSString(format: "\(sign)", string.substringWithRange(regexResult.rangeAtIndex(3)) as NSString).doubleValue * 60.0*60.0
            seconds += NSString(format: "\(sign)", string.substringWithRange(regexResult.rangeAtIndex(4)) as NSString).doubleValue * 60.0*60.0

        }
        return NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)
    }
```

When I called the function

```
var date = dateFromJSON("/Date(1434668400000+0100)/")
println("Date: \(date)")
```

Output is

```
Date: 2015-06-18 23:00:00 +0000
```

I don't understand whats going on why I am getting 1 day difference. May be I am doing something wrong while conversion ObjC to Swift or may be something else.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I checked your code and its giving correct date and even the `timestamp:1434668400` in your example is `2015-06-18 23:00:00` in GMT

Comment: Output time is GMT are you comparing it with your local time?

Comment: @HamzaAnsari I need it in UTC

Comment: The output here is in UTC and its correct time according to your string date

Comment: In Swift it's not necessary to use GCD to create the variable as singleton, just declare the variable with the `let` keyword   `let dateRegEx: NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\/date\\((-?\\d++)(?:([+-])(\\d{2})(\\d{2}))?\\)\\/$", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)!` or – if you really need a singleton –  initialize the variable lazily: `var dateRegEx: NSRegularExpression = {
  return NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\/date\\((-?\\d++)(?:([+-])(\\d{2})(\\d{2}))?\\)\\/$", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)!
}()`

Answer (score 1):

Check The Result generated from your code here:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for clarification but why the println return UTC time any idea ?

Comment: you are right but I need this function to return Jun 19, 2015 but it returning me 2015-08-18.. any suggestion for that.

Comment: Xcode Debugger prints NSDate in UTC format thats there default format

Comment: but in my application I need Jun 19, 2015 so what should i do ?

Comment: What timezone do you want your local timezone?

Comment: I just need 19 jun date anyhow timezone doesnt matter .. if I will go with specific timezone then It will create problem due to timeZone difference.

Comment: No dear I need 19th Jun for same timeStamp means ... for input /Date(1434668400000+0100)/ I need 19th Jun ... that shown in picture but println() print int 18th Jun

Comment: okh My bad as i can see your timezone is `GMT+0100` so you can do this  `return NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds + (0100*60))`