# iPhone:How to convert Regular Expression into Date Format?

Tags: iphone

Hello friends,

I have a string like "**/Date(1312628727617+0000)/**" and this regular expression convert into Date format in iPhone so please provide any link or any idea to develop this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [below method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone/2414159#2414159) and pass your regular expression date /Date(1312628727617+0000)/ as parameter.

```
- (NSDate*) getDateFromJSON:(NSString *)dateString
{
    // Expect date in this format "/Date(1268123281843)/"
    int startPos = [dateString rangeOfString:@"("].location+1;
    int endPos = [dateString rangeOfString:@")"].location;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(startPos,endPos-startPos);
    unsigned long long milliseconds = [[dateString substringWithRange:range] longLongValue];
    NSLog(@"%llu",milliseconds);
    NSTimeInterval interval = milliseconds/1000;
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateForm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateForm setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
  NSString *dateStr = [dateForm stringFromDate:<YourNSDateObject>];
  [dateForm setDateFormat:@"<Your Desired Date Format>"];
  NSDate *desireddate = [dateForm dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a  lot I used "/Date(1312628727617+0000)/" so its return 2011-08-06 16:35:27 +0530 but I want to display only 2011-08-06 16:35:27 so please help me

Comment: Then you can use NSDateFormatter and convert it to other date types but setting `setDateFormat:` of NSDateFormatter and then passing your NSDate object will give you the NSDate in desired format. Hope this is it.

Comment: hello parth How can i pass NSDate object in NSDateFormatter?? please help

Comment: @Nikunj Jadav: Please check the **EDIT** Section of my answer

Comment: You should probably give credit to toxaq for originally posting your first block of code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone/2414159#2414159

Comment: @Brad Larson: Yeah you are right. I just copied this block of code from where I used it in my project. And also just to make sure that the Nikunj Jadav gets a precise answer for a trivial problem and can work faster into it. No bad intensions :)

Comment: I've added a link back to the original answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `dateFromString:` at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html. You will find the many formats supported.

Comment: I suppose `dateFromString` would work  only if the date is NSString but in Native date format Like "12 July 2011" or may be "07-12-2011" or something similar. This function `dateFromString` would not work for date in the format `"/Date(1312628727617+0000)/"`

Comment: Agreed. I got the impression that the string used in the question was just an example & the actual strings may vary.

Answer (score 0):

See this: **- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string** @ below link

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDate