# Converting Date Format

Tags: objective-c, ios

How to convert this type of Date Format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss format.

```
                "DATE_OF_JOINING":"\/Date(1349634600000+0530)\/"
```

Comment: Is this a JSON object or a plain NSString?

Comment: Personally, if you have access to the webservice, I would just return it as a string. If you can't check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065278/879119

Comment: yes It is a Json Date Format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer a scanner over regular expressions to extract the time interval from the string

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"DATE_OF_JOINING" : @"Date(1357683534626+0530)"};

NSString *string = dict[@"DATE_OF_JOINING"];
NSString *intervalString;
NSString *offsetString;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
[scanner setScanLocation:[string rangeOfString:@"("].location+1];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-"] intoString:&intervalString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@")" intoString:&offsetString];

NSInteger hours = [[offsetString substringToIndex:3] integerValue];
NSInteger minutes = [[offsetString substringFromIndex:3] integerValue];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
offsetComponents.hour = hours;
offsetComponents.minute = minutes;

NSTimeInterval interval= [intervalString doubleValue];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval/1000];

date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:date options:0];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Hi, I need A help, If You are free, clarify me how to bind byte formatted image to png images. The link to my json Data is,                http://hrmsiphone.atrity.info:7006/HRMSService.svc/GetEmployDetailsByEmpName/EmployeeNo=1. please do me the favour...

Comment: Seriously: that's a question u should ask in a new question — after searching stackoverflow. Most likely it is answered before.

Comment: Btw: please start to accept answers. Otherwise many users won't feel like they want to answer u.

Answer (score 0):

use NSDateFormatter. This will let you format it many different ways, and into strings.

Here's apple's reference on the class for iOS:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html