# NSDate from timestamp

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have a string which I get from web-service response as
"**/Date(1366174800000-0500)/**".

I want to convert the given string to NSDate with proper time stamp.

I am able to convert the **1366174800000**(milliseconds) to NSDate using timeIntervalSince1970 API from apple, but I am not sure about the -500 appearing in the string.

Can somebody provide docs/examples for the same?

Regards,

Nirav

Comment: can you do anything about the -500, usually its written by zero padding i.e, -0500. If that is so there are many solutions [Parsing JSON Dates on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065278/767730)

Comment: Thanks. It was -0500. I edited. and using the link you provided it worked.

Answer (score 1):

-500 is the timezone.  That is 5 hours, 0 minutes before GMT (which is normally Atlantic/Boston, aka ET).

Comment: I thought the whole point of timestamps were to make timezones irrelevant.  A point in time is the same around the world, the only time timezones come into play is when you convert it to a local time.  I'm not saying it is not correct (-0500 definitely looks like a timezone), but wouldn't the best advice be to ignore it?