# How to read this json date "Date(1378357240047+0530)" to show it in a formatted way in ios

Tags: ios, json, date

I have tried doing this

```
NSString*
    dateAsString = @"/Date(1353720343336+0000)/";
    dateAsString = [dateAsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/Date("
                                                           withString:@""];
    dateAsString = [dateAsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+0000)/"
                                                           withString:@""];

unsigned long long milliseconds = [dateAsString longLongValue];
NSTimeInterval interval = milliseconds/1000;
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
```

But its not working.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON date." That string has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: the date is in that format i need to change it in dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: This would be a good one [Parsing JSON Date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065278/767730)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `NSDateFormatter` to parse from string to date, since the string date comes in a very particular format you must give a date formar, specified using ISO characters codification. Check this [tutorial](http://cybersam.com/ios-dev/quick-guide-to-ios-dateformatting) and [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) . 
Formatting it correctly you get an `NSDate` object and creating another date formatter you can specify a more readable format.