# Convert String to NSDate in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, nsdate

How to convert this date to `NSDate`

```
datestring = /Date(147410000000)/   //String from server response
```

Expected Output:

```
12/01/2014
```

I tried this. But I got nil.

```
let dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(datestring)
return date
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> "**147410000000**", i think this the **time-interval** which you are
>   getting from server.
>
> In your case,you need to trim the string and convert it From 
>   **/Date(147410000000)/** to **147410000000**

```
    var string : String = "1408709486" // (Put your string here)

    var timeinterval : NSTimeInterval = (string as NSString).doubleValue // convert it in to NSTimeInteral

    var dateFromServer = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:timeinterval) // you can the Date object from here

    println(dateFromServer) // for My Example it will print : 2014-08-22 12:11:26 +0000


    // Here i create a simple date formatter and print the string from DATE object. you can do it vise-versa. 

    var dateFormater : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    println(dateFormater.stringFromDate(dateFromServer)) // And then i can get the string like this : 2014-08-22
```

> **Check the comment section. Martin's comment will also help you to resolve your problem.**

Comment: "147410000000" gives the time in milliseconds, so you have to divide it by 1000.

Comment: Thanks Krupanshu!  Great solution. Usually sqlite store date as time interval. We can retrieve and reconvert into NSDate with that.

Answer (score 2):

You just use the wrong function at the **last line of your above mentioned code**

```
 var dateString = "01-02-2010"
 var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
 var dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

Comment: ok. i updated my question. Also my input string is like this /Date(147410000000)/

Answer (score 1):

Convert Date format in Swift:

```
let myDate = "2016-09-19 01:25:17"
let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let date = dateFormat.dateFromString(myDate)
dateFormat.dateFormat =  "yyyy-MM-dd"
let  newDate =  dateFormat.stringFromDate(date!)

print(newDate)
```

Comment: What If I need current date always and then pass it to this to get an NSDate instead using a hardcoded string.

Comment: Try this: let date = NSDate()

dateFormat.dateFormat =  "yyyy-dd-MM"

let  newDate =  dateFormat.stringFromDate(date)
         print(newDate)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Wolverine's code, I've written a function for **Swift 3 and iOS10**. Feel free to use:

```
func convertStringTimestampToStringDate(_ dateandTime: String) -> String {

let string : String = dateandTime
let timeinterval : TimeInterval = (string as NSString).doubleValue
let dateFromServer = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:timeinterval)

let dateFormater : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormater.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm a"
dateFormater.amSymbol = "AM"
dateFormater.pmSymbol = "PM"

let backToString = dateFormater.string(from: dateFromServer as Date)
print(dateFormater.string(from: dateFromServer as Date))
return backToString }
```

This should bring a solution like e.g.: "Oct 20, 2016, 03:30 AM" from an timestamp as input.