# How to convert a string into a date in swift

Tags: swift, string-to-datetime

I parsed the code "1442351280" from JSON and and I want to convert it to date in swift in medium style.

Comment: what happened when you attempted this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to this with with Foundation API

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1442351280)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned into [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601435/convert-string-to-nsdate-in-swift) post. It is a **time-interval** which you are getting from server.

And here is your answer:

```
var string : String = "1442351280"

var timeinterval : NSTimeInterval = (string as NSString).doubleValue

var dateFromServer = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:timeinterval)
print(dateFromServer)   //"sep 16,2015, 2:38 AM"
```