# How to deserialize JSON date to NSDate in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, json, date, datetime, jsonmodel

I have a Source date string

/Date(1455895287677-0500)/

in objective-c. I need to convert it to format like "2015-01-01 HH:MM:SS"

How can I convert it to Date or NSDate?

I'm using JSONModel, but it seems not working.

Comment: What does the number represent? For an UNIX timestamp it's too large

Comment: @vadian: Take the number, divide by 60*60*24*365.25 and you get about 46,000. We are 46 years past 1970. So obviously this is time since epoch in milliseconds

Comment: That makes sense :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a non-standard format for dates. Looks like milliseconds since 1970, plus time zone. You DON'T need to convert it to something like "2015-01-01 HH:MM:SS", you want an NSDate.

Take the string, check that it starts with /Date( and ends with )/ and remove these, check whether there is a + or - in between, split into the part before the + or - and the part starting with the + or -, call doubleValue for the first part and divide by 1000 (so you have seconds since 1970), call integerValue for the second part, so you get hours and minutes but in a decimal format. Take that integer value, divide by 100 to get hours, subtract hours times 100 from the number, what remains is minutes. Add hours * 3600 and minutes * 60 to the time. Then [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970].

Obviously do some testing, log if there is anything that you didn't expect and make sure you handle it.

Comment: Actually, this link has the implementation for the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone , but still thanks for the explaining of the format.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my question, I originally tried to use the JSONModel to deserialize date string, like "/Date(1455895287677-0500)/" but it failed. The reason is that NSDate is not supported by the JSONModel.

However, fortunately, we can achieve this goal by a few steps by modifying and adding methods to JSONModel.

1. Add **[NSDate class]** to **allowedJSONTypes** in JSONModel.m if you use JSONModel(https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) to deserialize your JSON string.
2. Create a file called **JSONValueTransformer+NSDate.m** and **.h** file as well (you can rename them) in folder **JSONModelTransformations**.
3. Add this code to your newly created **.m** file and don't forget write interface in **.h** file (I planed to add the methods to JSONValueTransformer.m file, but to tell the difference, I decided to create new .m and .h files).

```
- (NSDate *) NSDateFromNSString:(NSString*)string {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:APIDateFormat];
    return [formatter dateFromString:string]; 
}
```

4. Add method from provided by @jasongregori in [Parsing JSON dates on IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757303/parsing-json-dates-on-iphone) to your newly created **.m** file.
5. The method in **step 3** will handle the date format like "2013-08-26T15:23:37.832Z". If the date format is like this /Date(***********-****)/, you have to call method in **step 4**.